# Apply changes in flask-app while debugging without having to reload the entire app

Tags: flask, pycharm

I have a flask app which takes ~5 minutes to start up, due to loading of various stuff.
I then found a small bug which I wanted to test. If I then set a break-point, and want to test that change, it seems like I have to re-run the debug i.e reload the entire app thus waiting 5 minutes just for changing e.g `str(e)` to `repr(e)`.

Is there a way to ommit that such that I just have to make a new request to see if the changes have an effect? I'm using PyCharm if that has anything to say

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Werkzeug` for hot reloading.

```
pip install Werkzeug
```

Here is an example, of how you can use it.

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    run_simple('localhost', 5000, app, use_reloader=True)
```

or you can use debug=True

```
app.run(debug=True)
```